# trying to understand some functions related to zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
/**
    * getter method, basically same as offsetGet().
    *
    * This method can be called from an object of type Zend_Registry, or it
    * can be called statically.  In the latter case, it uses the default
    * static instance stored in the class.
    *
    * @param string $index - get the value associated with $index
    * @return mixed
    * @throws Zend_Exception if no entry is registerd for $index.
    */
public static function get($index)
    {
        $instance = self::getInstance();

        if (!$instance->offsetExists($index))
        {
            if ($instance->lazyLoad($index, $return))
            {
                return $return;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Zend_Exception("No entry is registered for key '$index'");
            }
        }

        return $instance->offsetGet($index);
    }
...
public static function getDb()
    {
        return self::get('db');
    }

...
```

This is taken from Xenforo/Application.php, Although the comment is clear, but still have some questions:

1. `$instance = self::getInstance();` what does this line mean here?
2. `$instance->lazyLoad;` I could not find the declaration of this method:lazyLoad, is it also Zend file?
3. `$instance->offsetGet($index)`, I saw its declaration in **SPL.php**, it is:
   `public function offsetGet ($index) {}`,  but it is empty inside {}, so how does this function?

Comment: `get` is taken from Zend/Registry.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some brief explanation about your threee question

**1. $instance = self::getInstance(); what does this line mean here?**

**Answer 1.** getInstance method is used to get that class instance without doing $test = new class_name(); 
getInstance method is static so you can get that class instance without declaring new class_name(); 
in getInstance method its checking does _instance is set? if not set then create own class instance and then return that instance.

**2. $instance->lazyLoad; I could not find the declaration of this method:lazyLoad, is it also Zend file?**

**Answer 2.** you can understand about lazyload from below link so you could have better idea about lazyload. [Link](http://tech.vg.no/2012/06/01/lazy-loading-resources-with-zend-framework-bootstrap/)

**3. $instance->offsetGet($index), I saw its declaration in SPL.php, it is: public function offsetGet ($index) {}, but it is empty inside {}, so how does this function?**

**Answer 3.** This method can be called from an object of type Zend_Registry, or it can be called statically. In the latter case, it uses the default static instance stored in the class.

Parameters:
string  $index  - get the value associated with $index
Returns:
mixed
Exceptions:
Zend_Exception  if no entry is registerd for $index.

pls let me know if i could help you more..

Comment: Thanks for your help. It helps me to get better idea of it, it may take time to totally understand.